# Form alignment left side to right side

Tags: forms, layout, best-practice, conventions, placement

I am very new to UX and I find my form to be sloppy.

Is it an alignment problem? Should I align the text on the right side with the text in the left side of the form? For example: should I align " Help ProTel" with "Duration (hh:mm)"?

Or do you have some other suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this article. 
https://uxplanet.org/the-18-must-do-principles-in-the-form-design-fe89d0127c92

You should not have inputs one next to the other. You should place duration below description for a logical user flow.

Comment: Thank you, Cristian. I upvoted your answer, but I do not have enough reputation for my vote to be publicly showed. What I was trying to do is to grab user's attention to only the left side of the form as a mean to simplify things considering the right side is prefilled or not so important, but my design is clearly a form and the best-practice is to have all elements in the same column. Or step further away from this form shape.

Answer (score 1):

Structurally your form should be a single column, nothing should be side by side. Also labels should always sit on top of the inputs, instead of next to them.

The reason behind this it is that we read left to right and then top to bottom, that is different in other parts of the world though.

Also make sure the spacing between the label and the corresponding input is less than the label and the previous input so it isn’t confusing which label matches with each input.